# Make images flow from right to left within a NSImageView on click

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, macos-sierra

I am wondering how it is possible to animate the change of an image in an imageView on OS X. I know about fading in (and out), but my question is how to let the images flow in (from right to left) when the user clicks on a button to display the next/previous image. For example, it should look like a "PageView" on iOS, when you scroll, like on the websites ([like this but with Swift 3...](http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/#slider-image-3)).

So the user should be able to control the image flow with buttons and the images shouldn't slide every 5 seconds or so.

I attached a picture of my current storyboard.

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kj5P.png)

Thanks for answers! :-)

Comment: If you're willing to use 3rd party libraries, have you looked into https://github.com/floschliep/FLOPageViewController?

Comment: @PeterTao Hey, thanks for that, doesn't look bad ;-) I actually don't really want to use 3rd party libraries, but I think I will have a look at it and maybe - if it's not to complex -  reproduce it on my own. Thank you so far.

Comment: @PeterTao Could you just write your comment in an answer? That would be kind as I would mark the problem as solved then. Thanks

Comment: Sure thing, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution depends on a third party library but if you would like,
 [FLOPageViewController](http://github.com/floschliep/FLOPageViewController) will do the trick. It may be worthwhile to go through their code and try to implement it in house as this library may not be actively updated. Good luck!

[image]

Image taken from https://github.com/floschliep/FLOPageViewController